# Error when I run this command python manage.py makemigrations blog in python django in models.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql

*I get an error*, when I run this command `python manage.py makemigrations blog` in `python django` in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()`enter code here`

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: I see a Class definition (with an inner class definition and faulty Indentation?), but I don't see where this code should start running, when the script gets executed? Can you elabarate on that.

Comment: "An error" is alway the worst error to debug. Please edit your question and add the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of issues with your code:

- Indentation
- User class import
- use `Blog` instead of `blog.Blog`

a quick fix:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()`enter code here`

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: wait i try i will give you feed back

Comment: still experiencing an error at line 29  `File "C:\django\membersite\blog\models.py", line 29
    self.save()` `enter code here`

Comment: Well, if you can't figure out what that error mean, not really sure if you have the python basics to work with Django

Comment: i am a beginner in django

Comment: Change `self.save()enter code here` to just `self.save()` in line 29